# How to replace Groupbox Text property with a Radio Button?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, radio-button

I have been trying to edit the **GroupBox** Class but the default Text property returns String and **RadioButton** is object. I couldn't figure out what's missing.

**Important**
What I am trying to do is to change the text which is *GroupBox1* and instead of that put a radioButton to allow me to enable the form. I don't want to put multiple radioButtons inside groupBox.

I also was able to do it in HTML simple as:

```
<form>
<fieldset>
    <legend>
        <input type="radio">
        <label>RadioButton1<label>
    </legend>
</fieldset>
```

Which for curiosity it will render this form:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/673x3.png)

Also I have seen a similar form while fixing recently some Network Problems, at WLAN properties under IPV4 where it asks about DNS. Here is the preview of form.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RT2Hp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typically done by overlaying `RadioButton` on top of `GroupBox` control. You may want to set a groupbox's label to sequence of spaces, so that its border is drawn correctly.

Comment: Yeah I could possibly do that. Hope I'll figure it out soon how to do it.